# 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found' ERROR in connecting pdo with odbc in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to connect the Microsoft access database using PDO with odbc. I have mounted the files on network drive and I am trying to access them, but I am getting the following error:

> PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)'': file not found'.

Here is my code:

```
$dbName = "/info/new.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$database = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq= $dbName;Uid=admin");
```

Comment: MS Access can only be used in Windows environments which require backslashes for file reference. And for PHP, double backslahes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: so how i have to access the file ?

Comment: environment : windows

Comment: Then why are you using forward slashes? Did you try backslashes as I advised in first comment?

Comment: i mean you are saying like this : \\info\\new.mdb  ?

Comment: Why aren't there drive letters (`C:\\`` and `D:\\``)? If using absolute path of a network and they already begin with backslashes, you may need to double up those: `\\\\info\\new.mdb`

Comment: i tried i got the same error Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found

Comment: Please update with your post with attempt. Dbq must retain full path. I see no `.mdb` extension.

Comment: i updated ,i forgot to included in the code

Comment: `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` in php.ini?

Comment: I see no attempt at backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure the odbc extension is activated in the **php.ini** file. Just remove the `;` to enable it.

```
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Then for connection, please use the exact file location with proper convention (it should be using backslash). The example is below.

```
try {
    $file_location = "C:\Users\PC1\Desktop\your_database.mdb";
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$file_location;Uid=Admin");

    //Do your program stuffs here

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```